# Getting multicolumn qualifiers, INNER JOINs, and UNIONs to work together

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to get a list of IDs from three tables.

```
table_one
---------
| id | other_data |

table_two
---------
| this_id | user_id | time_qual |

table_three
---------
| this_id | second_qual |
```

I want to get a list back of `table_one` `id`s with the following qualifications:

1. the `id` is also found in `table_three`'s `this_id`
2. `second_qual` in `table_three` is equal to 1
3. `this_id` in `table_two` equals `table_one`'s `id` AND in the same row, `table_two`'s `user_id` equals the php variable `$user_id` AND `time_qual` in that row equals 1.
4. but also include `id`s that qualify for #1 and #2, and not #3 if `table_one`'s `id` and the php variable `$user_id` isn't found on the **same row** of `table_two`

This is my attempt:

```
        SELECT tb1.id FROM table_one tb1
          INNER JOIN table_two tb2
          INNER JOIN table_three tb3
          WHERE tb2.this_id = tb1.id
           AND tb3.this_id = tb1.id
           AND tb3.second_qual = 1
           AND ((tb2.user_id = $user_id AND tb2.time_qual = 1)
              OR ($user_id NOT IN (SELECT user_id FROM table_two)))
           GROUP BY tb1.id
```

I'm guessing there should be a `UNION` in there and that `tb2.this_id = tb1.id` eliminates the results I want from #4, but I'm not sure what to do.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To the best of my ability to parse your requirements, I think this is the answer.  Let me know if it misses and I can amend:

```
SELECT t1.id
FROM table_three t3 
RIGHT JOIN table_one t1 
  ON t1.id=t3.this_id 
LEFT JOIN table_two t2 
  ON t1.id=t2.this_id 
WHERE (t3.this_id IS NOT NULL AND t3.second_qual=1) 
  AND ((t2.this_id IS NOT NULL AND t2.user_id=1 AND t2.time_qual=1) 
    OR t2.this_id IS NULL);
```

Comment: thank you for all the help. the concept was hard to parse for sure. ends up that this query above will do it except to the last `AND` I had to add a 2nd `OR` (`OR ($user_id NOT IN (SELECT user_id FROM t2.user_id)))`  Once again, thanks!